# autocomplete-plus blocked by dartlang in atom?

Tags: dart, atom-editor

I am using atom 1.9.8, with autocomplete-plus 2.31.0, and [dartlang](https://atom.io/packages/dartlang) 0.6.35 and autocomplete seems blocked in dart files.  Works just fine in other file types.

Anyone else run into this?  Solutions?

Comment: Did you install the Dart plugin? It comes with it's own autocompletion (AFAIK, I don't use Atom myself).

Comment: Yes, dartlang is the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The good news here is appears by 0.6.45 this is resolved!